# building NFA for { a^p; p is a prime number, m is a fixed number and m >p >0 }

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

$\{a^p; p$  is a prime number, $m$ is a fixed number and $m\geq p \geq 0 \}$

I know this is regular since it is finite, but I don't understand how to build an NFA for this if we do not know what $m$ is. Is there a way to draw the NFA regardless?

Comment: You either know what $m$ is, and then you can build the DFA, or you don't, and then you don't know what language you are talking about.

Comment: @Dmitry I think the question is: what is an algorithm which takes $m$ as an input and outputs a description of an NFA that accepts the language stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your DFA has states $S_0$ to $S_m$ and E. You start at state $S_0$.

Any state transitions to E if the next input symbol is not a. States $S_m$ and E transition to state E on any input; state $S_i$ for 0 ≤ i < m goes to state $S_{i+1}$ on input a.

$S_i$ is an accepting state if and only if i is a prime. All other states are non-accepting.